# Django text input typeahead autocomplete

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a simple Model

```
class Thing(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='de')
    date_from = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
```

The `name` field should be prepopulated in the form while typing with existing names from existing rows. I had a look at django-select2 or django-autocomplete-light. But both packages are mostly used for ForeignKeys. In fact I do so too in my project.

Does anybody know a simple way how to solve this task without hacking to much in JavaScript.

Comment: I think you'll have to go down the javascript route. Make your rows available as a json object in your template and then use a js plugin for the actual typeahead part. I'd like to be proven wrong though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without going the JavaScript route, I would use a datalist.

```html
<label for="name-id">Name: </label>
    
<input list="names" name="name" id="name-id" />
    
<datalist id="names">
    <option value="Vione">
    <option value="Veya">
    <option value="Argo">
    <option value="Paro">
    <option value="Esena">
    <option value="Sanar">
</datalist>
```

This could be implemented in Django as follows:

```
# Your view

class ThingCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Thing
    success_url = reverse('thing-list')

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class)

        # make the 'name' field use a datalist to autocomplete
        form.fields['name'].widget.attrs.update({'list': 'names'})

        return form

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # add `names` to the context to populate the datalist
        context['names'] = Thing.objects.values_list('name', flat=True)

        return context
```

```
# Your form
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.as_p }}

    <datalist id="names">
        {% for name in names %}
        <option value="{{ name }}">
        {% endfor %}
    </datalist>

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Comment: Great solution for smaller lists. In my case I am expecting quite a lot of entries. Many thanks. I think I have to crawl down the cruel typeahead, ajax, json path

Comment: my pleasure. I will post my solution

Comment: @mbieren You mention datalist is only suitable for smaller lists. How many are too many for datalist? I have a list of ~5000 entries. Would that be too large?

Answer (score -1):

I am using the great jquery typeahead plugin from https://github.com/running-coder/jquery-typeahead now. My Form for the thing model is

```
class ThingShareCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.layout = Layout(
        Div(
            Div('mode', css_class='col-md-2'),
            Div(Div(Field(Div(PrependedText('name', '<span class="fa fa-search"></span>'),
                            css_class='typeahead__query'),
                        css_class='typeahead__field'),
                    css_class='typeahead__container'),
                css_class='col-md-5'),
```

....

Later on in the class Meta

```
class Meta:

    model = ThingShare
    fields = ['mode', 'name', 'source', 'source_text', 'date_from', 'date_to']

    widgets = {
        'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'js-typeahead-name',
                                       'name' : 'q',
                                       'type' : 'search',
                                       'autocomplete': 'off',
                                       }),
```

This can then be used like :

```
typeof $.typeahead === 'function' && $.typeahead({
        input: ".js-typeahead-name",
        minLength: 1,
        hint: false,
        source: {
            country: {
                data: data.countries
            },
        },
        callback: {
            onClickAfter: function (node, a, item, event) {
                event.preventDefault();
```

as described in the great doc and examples. This library is worth a closer look. I still have to implement my AJAX call which is basically a select distinct on my model "Thing". Pretty simple now

Regards

Michael